# creating mdx for Airwatch

Tags: virtual-machine, airwatch

I am creating mobile application in android and iOS. For Citrix Xen mobile user I have generated a MDX file using Citrix MDX toolkit. It is working good. Now I need to create a MDX file for Airwatch. Please can anyone tell me which tool I need to use for generating a mdx file for Airwatch both android and iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MDM version for AirWatch does not generate a MDX file, MDX file is for Citrix only.

AirWatch generates APK type file for Android, and it is an Android Apk, you can directly run it on Android devices.

AirWatch provices Android SDK [AAR] for Android Developers, you can use this SDK [AAR] under Android Studio to enable the EMM functions, just like the Google Service SDK.

Comment: How it generate. Is this android apk? or is this have some different way to create  pack for Airwatch

Comment: @ShanmugapriyaD, I update the answer for your comments.

Comment: Thank u for the clarification. Please can u any related URL about this.